# Call to 'abs' is ambiguous in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, std, objective-c++

I have a problem in this code snippet, it is giving the error `call to 'abs' is ambiguous`.

```
for (NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < count; idx++) {
    if ((std::abs(toValues[idx] - previousValues[idx]) >= t) || (std::abs(previous2Values[idx] - previousValues[idx]) >= t)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That looks more like C++ than Swift...

Comment: Because it is Objective-C++. I edited the question.

Comment: `Ambiguous` means open to more than one interpretation. What is the type of `toValues[idx] - previousValues[idx]`?

Comment: I cannot see any Objective-C code in it.

Comment: @Rhymoid But overloading and static typing is a typical problem to both C++ and Swift. ;-)

Comment: What the hell is Objective-C++ ??? There is a language called Objective-C and another, very different, called C++. But this is the first time I hear about Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible causes for `call to some_function() is ambiguous`.

1. **Arguments in a function call do not match those in any function
   declaration.** 
   I hope the arrays `toValues` and  `previousValues` are of the same type. In this case check if the value `toValues[idx] - previousValues[idx]` is of a type that is allowed by abs() as an argument. According to C++11 standard the allowed values are *int*, *long int* and *long long int*.  
   Perhaps you could cast the value of the `toValues[idx] - previousValues[idx]` to integer or another permitted type to rule out this as a cause like below :

   `(int)toValues[idx] - previousValues[idx]`
2. **The same function is defined more than once**

   abs() is a massively overloaded function. You could check if it is included multiple times in your code using multiple header files. For example inclusion of math.h and cmath.h will result in a duplicate abs() function which will lead to ambiguity. However, such inclusion of headers does not make any sense. Rather such inclusion is accidental.

Comment: Please mention what the problem was.